# Armazenar entradas e ao final mostrar o percentual de escolhas

Tags: c

Estou tentando resolver um exercício e estou quebrando a cabeça. Consiste em os usuários escolherem seu SO predileto e ao final o programa mostrar o percentual de cada escolha. Só que eu sequer estou conseguindo entender o pq de as escolhas não estarem sendo armazenadas... As críticas são bem vindas!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int i, escolha, windowsserver, unix, linux, netware, macos, outros;
float mwin, munix, mlinux, mnetware, mmacos, moutros, total;


printf("Bem vindo!\n");

while (i = 1, i++)
{


    printf("Escolha o seu sistema operacional predileto\n 1 - Windows Server\n 2 - Unix\n 3 - Linux \n 4 - Netware\n 5 - Mac OS\n 6 - Outros\n 0 - Ver estatisticas\n Escolha: ");
    scanf("%d", &escolha);


    if (escolha == 1)
    {
        windowsserver++;
    }
    if (escolha == 2)
    {
        unix++;
    }
    if (escolha == 3)
    {
        linux++;
    }
    if (escolha == 4)
    {
        netware++;
    }
    if (escolha == 5)
    {
        macos++;
    }
    if (escolha == 6)
    {
        outros++;
    }

    if (escolha == 0)
    {
        total = windowsserver + unix + linux + netware + macos + outros;
        mwin = total/windowsserver*100;
        munix = total/munix*100;
        mlinux = total/mlinux*100;
        mnetware = total/mnetware*100;
        mmacos = total/mmacos*100;
        moutros = total/moutros*100;
        printf("Percentual de escolhas:\n Windows Server: %4.2f porcento\n Unix: %4.2f porcento\n Linux: %4.2f porcento\n Netware: %4.2f porcento\n Mac OS: %4.2f porcento\n Outros: %4.2f porcento\n", &mwin,&munix,&mlinux,&mnetware,&mmacos,&moutros);

    }




}



return 0;
```

}

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: O que exatamente você pretende ao declarar a condição dessa forma: `while (i = 1, i++)` ?

Comment: Boa tarde! Minha ideia com while (i = 1, i++) era fazer o programa ficar em looping até ser apertado o 0 para mostrar as estatísticas, muito errado?

Comment: A ideia do programa é de armazenar as respostas de uma pesquisa de qual o OS preferido do usuário. Cada vez que se escolhe uma resposta o programa volta ao início. ao apertar 0, o programa captura todas as respostas dadas e  coloca elas em formato de porcentagem para cada OS.

Comment: Se você deseja que o loop seja executado enquanto o valor de `escolha` for diferente de 0, o seu loop deveria ter sido declarado `while(escolha != 0)`. Aí, para garantir que o loop seja executado, ao menos uma vez, você poderia ou usar um `do.. while` ou inicializar escolha com um valor diferente de 0. Quanto à inicialização, você não inicializou o valor de nenhuma das suas variáveis, então, elas estão assumindo valores aleatórios e é o que provavelmente está produzindo o erro no seu código.

Comment: Obrigado pelo auxílio Vander! o loop agora está correto, inicializei todas as variáveis com =0. Mas o programa segue não acumulando as entradas nas respectivas variáveis. Ao fim ele mostra a % de todas variáveis como 0.0, ignorando todas as entradas.